# Calculating the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

> Calculate the following determinant of a matrix of order $n$:
>   $$\begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
> 1 & a_1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
> 1 & 1 & a_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
> 1 & 0 & 1 & a_3 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
> \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
> \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
> 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & a_{n-1}
> \end{bmatrix}$$

What I did was to get rid of the $1$ at the top right corner and then applying transpose, at this point the determinant is in button echelon form so the determinant is the product of the values in the diagonal.

This is the result I got:
$$\prod^{n-2}_{i=1} a_i\left(a_{n-1}a_{n-2}-1\right)\left(a_{n-1}a_{n-2}\right)$$

Is it correct?

Edit: it's wrong.

Edit2: got a different solution now, although it's strange: $$(\prod^{n-1}_{i=1}a_i)^2(\prod^{n-2}_{i=1}a_i)$$

Comment: @alexwlchan thanks, it would've taken me forever to type the matrix manually.

Comment: How precisely did you "get rid" of the 1 at the top right corner? (And there's no need to transpose; computing the determinant of lower and upper triangular matrices is identical.)

Comment: @MichaelC.Grant I wanted to add those steps now but I found a mistake... That solution is wrong.

Comment: OK. It shouldn't be difficult to eliminate the 1 with some sort of Gaussian Elimination operation, but then you have to take that operation into account as well when computing the determinant!

Comment: @MichaelC.Grant I think I got it, I get a diagonal matrix and on both right bottom and top left this value $\prod^{n-1}_{i=1}a_i$ so the determinant is: $$(\prod^{n-1}_{i=1}a_i)^2(\prod^{n-2}_{i=1}a_i)$$

Comment: That looks a bit suspicious to me, frankly. I wouldn't expect the determinant to be cubic in each term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  Here's how to relate such a determinant of order $n$ to the analogous determinant of order $n-1$; this is the core of a proof by induction of the formula you're looking for.  I'll illustrate with $n=5$.  (When you generalize, you'll have to be careful with the signs.)
\begin{align*}
\left|\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & a_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & a_2 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & a_3 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & a_4
\end{matrix}\right|
&=
\left|\begin{matrix}
a_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & a_2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & a_3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & a_4
\end{matrix}\right|
+
\left|\begin{matrix}
1 & a_1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & a_2 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & a_3 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right|
&&\text{(expanding in first row)} \\
&= a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4
+
\left|\begin{matrix}
1 & a_1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & a_2 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & a_3 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right|
&&\text{(diagonal matrix)} \\
\\ \\
&= a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4
-
\left|\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & a_1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & a_2 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & a_3 \\
\end{matrix}\right|
&&\text{($3$ row swaps)}
\end{align*}
(Expanding in the second row also leads to a nice recurrence.)

Comment: Oh nice. Is that Fibonacci recurrence by any chance ?

Comment: Not related to Fibonacci as far as I can see.